# Multiple Foreign Keys to multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

My database design is looking like this. Short form:

```
CREATE TABLE LANDSLIDE (
      LNUMBER SERIAL NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (LNUMBER)
      ...
```

There 4 Tables like (parts of a landslide)

```
CREATE TABLE SCARP (
      SCPNUM CHAR(7) NOT NULL, 
      LNUMBER SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
      FOREIGN KEY (LNUMBER) REFERENCES LANDSLIDE (LNUMBER) ON DELETE CASCADE,
      ...
                   );
```

e.g. scpnum = scp0001

```
CREATE TABLE ACCUMULATION (
      ACCUNUM CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
      LNUMBER SMALLINT NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (LNUMBER) REFERENCES LANDSLIDE (LNUMBER) ON DELETE CASCADE,
      ...
                          );
```

e.g. accunum = accu0001

```
CREATE TABLE FRONT (
      FRNUM CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
      LNUMBER SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
      FOREIGN KEY (LNUMBER) REFERENCES LANDSLIDE (LNUMBER) ON DELETE CASCADE,
      ...
                    );
```

e.g. frnum = fr0001

```
CREATE TABLE OTHER (
      OTHERNUM CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
      LNUMBER SMALLINT NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (LNUMBER) REFERENCES LANDSLIDE (LNUMBER) ON DELETE CASCADE,
      ...
                   );
```

e.g. othernum = other0001

There is another table, called material (different stones, soils on the different parts).

```
CREATE TABLE MATERIAL (
     MATNUMBER VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
     ROCK,
     DISTRIBUTION,
     ...
     PRIMARY KEY(MATNUMBER,ROCK,DISTRIBUTION,...),
     CONSTRAINT material_matnumber_scarp_fkey FOREIGN KEY 
     (MATNUMBER) REFERENCES SCARP (SCPNUM) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT material_matnumber_accumulation_fkey FOREIGN KEY 
     (MATNUMBER) REFERENCES ACCUMULATION (ACCUNUM) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT material_matnumber_front_fkey FOREIGN KEY 
     (MATNUMBER) REFERENCES FRONT (FRNUM) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT material_matnumber_other_fkey FOREIGN KEY 
     (MATNUMBER) REFERENCES OTHER (OTHERNUM) ON DELETE CASCADE
                      );
```

When I insert data to material (after making entries to the other tables), it returns an error.
ERROR: insert or update on table "material" violates foreign key constraint "material_matnumber_accumulation_fkey"
DETAIL: Key (matnumber)=(scp0001) is not present in table "accumulation"

The table material should look like this:

```
MATNUMBER | ROCK | DISTRIBUTION | ...
----------+------+--------------+------
scp0001   |   A  |    lateral   | ...
scp0001   |   B  |    lateral   | ...
accu0001  |   B  |    central   | ...
scp0002   |   C  |    NULL      |
accu0002  |   A  |    lateral   |
fr0002    |   A  |    NULL      |
scp0003   |   B  |    cantral   |
accu0003  |   B  |    lateral   |
other0003 |   C  |    NULL      |
```

Every entry is unique, because of the matnumber!

Comment: Well, is there a row in `ACCUMULATION` where `ACCUNUM='scp0001'`?

Comment: What you are trying to do does not work. The matnumber `scp0001` will have to exist in all tables the foreign keys reference too, not just `SCRAP`. You will have to create multiple columns, one for each foreign key. You could group them all in one column using a view or something.

Comment: I think your foreign keys are backwards.

Comment: read up on table inheritance

Comment: check my answer you **FRONT** table cannot accommodate scp0001 cos it can accommodate only up to scp000 char 6.

Comment: thanks for the answers. There is no row in ACCUMULATION where ACCUNUM='scp0001'. So I have to create multiple columns in MATERIAL.
That means I will have many NULL entries. And that's Ok?
    SCPNUM| ACCUNUM| FRNUM| OTHERNUM| ROCK| DISTRIBUTION| ...
  --------+--------+------+---------+-----+-------------+-----
  scp0001 | NULL   | NULL | NULL    | A   | B           | ...

Comment: What is relationship between `Material` and `Scarp` (and the other 3 tables) supposed to be? A Scarp can have many materials? Or a Material is one of the 4 (either Scarp or Accumulation or Front or Other)?

Comment: Sorry for my last comment

Comment: A SCARP can have many material. And one Material belongs exactly to one SCARP and not the other parts.

Comment: OK. And a Material can also belong to exactly one Accumulation, right (if it doesn't belong to a Scarp)? Or to exactly one Front. Correct?

Comment: Yes a MATERIAL can belong exactly to one ACCUMULATION, FRONT or OTHER. I want to realize this with the primary key that contains also the number of the part (e.g. scp0001). It could be that may be scp0001 or accu0001 or front0003 have the same entries in the table MATERIAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a common problem that can be solved with the supertype / subtype pattern. You could also have 4 nullable FK columns in the `Material` table but here is my suggestion:

```
CREATE TABLE Landslide  (                  --- no change here
      LNumber SERIAL NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (LNumber)
      ...
```

You say: *"There 4 Tables like (parts of a landslide)"*

So, we create an additional `LandslidePart` table (this is our "supertype" table):

```
CREATE TABLE LandslidePart (
      PartType CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
      PartNumber INT NOT NULL, 
      LNumber SMALLINT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (PartType, PartNumber),
      CHECK (PartType IN ('S', 'A', 'F', 'O')),       --- the 4 subtypes
      FOREIGN KEY (LNumber) REFERENCES Landslide (LNumber) ON DELETE CASCADE,
      ...                                             --- other columns that are
                                                      --- common in all 4 tables
                   );
```

Then we have our 4 ("subtype") tables, slightly altered:

```
CREATE TABLE Scarp (
      PartType CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
      PartNumber INT NOT NULL, 
      PRIMARY KEY (PartType, PartNumber),
      CHECK (PartType = 'S'), 
      FOREIGN KEY (PartType, PartNumber) 
          REFERENCES LandslidePart (PartType, PartNumber) 
          ON DELETE CASCADE,
      ...                           --- columns that are related to Scarp
                   );

CREATE TABLE Accumulation (
      PartType CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
      PartNumber INT NOT NULL, 
      PRIMARY KEY (PartType, PartNumber),
      CHECK (PartType = 'A'), 
      FOREIGN KEY (PartType, PartNumber) 
          REFERENCES LandslidePart (PartType, PartNumber) 
          ON DELETE CASCADE,
      ...                           --- columns that are related to Accumulation 
                   );

 --- We define in a similar way the other 2 tables: "Front" and "Other"
```

Now we can define the `Material` table that **references the "supertype"** (`LandslidePart`) table and not any of the four:

```
CREATE TABLE Material (
     PartType CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
     MatNumber INT NOT NULL,
     Rock,
     Distribution,
     ...
     PRIMARY KEY(PartType, MatNumber, Rock, Distribution, ...),
     CONSTRAINT material_matnumber_landslidepart_fkey 
     FOREIGN KEY (PartType, MatNumber) 
         REFERENCES LandslidePart (PartType, PartNumber) 
         ON DELETE CASCADE,
                      );
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. This looks pretty clear to me. I will try this!
Can I create other tables, like material with the same relation to the parts? Like another called WATER, for example.

Comment: It's me again. When I want to Select the part 'scarp' of a landslide, with any attribute (like 'form') I get an error that parttype is ambiguous. How would you query this?? Do I have to rename the parttypes in the part-tables to an unique name?

Comment: Can you post the query you use? (new question would be fine)

Comment: I didn't remember of referencing columns with an AS alias. So I will try this at first. Sorry! =)

Answer (score 0):

Check your foreign keys length and data types.

All the following reference to `MATNUMBER VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL`, in `MATERIAL`

```
SCPNUM CHAR(7) NOT NULL, *should be* SCPNUM VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
ACCUNUM CHAR(8) NOT NULL *should be* ACCUNUM VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
FRNUM CHAR(6) NOT NULL, *should be* FRNUM VarCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Down voter I beg your pardon how do you cascade when length of the key is mismatching? scp0001 not going to be in *FRONT* table as FRNUM it can accomodate only scp000.

Comment: Good to know why down vote otherwise will think it is sour grapes

Comment: I haven't downvoted but do you really think that these changes will resolve the issue? Having a column that references 4 separate tables, with obviously different values is the problem here (or better, one of the problems). Your answer will just help the OP pass the `CREATE TABLE` issue. He won't be able to insert any rows at all  though.

Comment: yes the way cascade has been used it will. given are the sample key out of many OP says "e.g. fr0001" are you certain about the foreign keys are not in the table?

Comment: Oh, you are right about that part, I misread the question. He has already defined the Foreign Key constraints but he cannot insert into the table. I don't expect your answer to solve that.

Comment: ok @ypercube just got out from a conundrum. it appears OP changed some vital elements since last time I checked it. hope your solution will nail it. good luck take it easy.